# Magento - is there any way to apply second coupon code programmatically

Tags: php, magento

I want something like this. once user apply couponcode ( cart rule ) then script automatically apply second rule on cart pragmatically.

means once user add couponcode then i check condition and second rule apply automatically on cart.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Magneto not able to add two coupons on same time so we are using one module which help us to do this.

Answer (score 0):

You could build an observer that triggers when `catalogrule_after_apply` is fired.

At this point you can inspect what coupon has been applied and then make your decision on what next one to apply.

Comment: i just want to know that how to update couponcode rules on apply time. what means when we user try to apply couponcode then we get coupon then update coupon code then apply.. is this possible that to update couponcode on run time.